# Compilation error on creating nodes of a BST from a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, compiler-errors, binary-search-tree

In my code, there is a binary tree struct defined as :

```
typedef struct bintreestruct *bintree;

struct bintreestruct
{
  double num;
  char *s;
  bintree l, r;
};
```

I wanted to insert a node into this binary search tree. Here is the function:

```
void insbintree(double i, char *s, bintree *t)
{
  if (t == NULL)
  {
    bintree temp = (struct bintreestruct *)malloc(sizeof(struct bintreestruct));
    temp->s = s;
    temp->num = i;
    temp->l = temp->r = NULL;
    return temp;
  }
  if (strcmp(s, t->s) < 0)
    t->l = insert(t->l, s);
  else if (strcmp(s, t->s) >= 0)
    t->r = insert(t->r, s);
  return t;
}
```

I am getting the error  `error: ‘*t’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’? 62 |   if (strcmp(s, t->s) < 0)`
Either I am creating the new node incorrectly or accessing the elements inside in
the wrong way using pointers. Not sure how to correct this error

Comment: `bintree *t` - `bintree` is an alias to `struct bintreestruct *`, therefore `bintree *t` is a pointer to pointer. And that, kids, is why we do NOT hide pointer types in typedef aliases. Related: `return t;` and `return temp;` are both invalid. The function returns `void`.

Comment: @chintu How are you going to call the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to write a recursive function because it calls itself.

As the function has return statements with expressions then its return type shall not be `void`.

Also this parameter declaration `bintree *t` is equivalent to `struct bintreestruct **` due to this typedef

```
typedef struct bintreestruct *bintree;
```

But within the function you are trying to use it as having the type `struct bintreestruct *`.

And in these calls of the function itself

```
t->l = insert(t->l, s);
t->r = insert(t->r, s);
```

there are used incomplete and not correctly ordered lists of arguments.

Taking all this into account the function can be declared and defined  at least the following way

```
bintree insbintree(double i, char *s, bintree t)
{
    if (t == NULL)
    {
        t = malloc( sizeof( struct bintreestruct ) );
        t->s = s;
        t->num = i;
        t->l = t->r = NULL;
    }
    else if ( strcmp(s, t->s) < 0 )
    {
        t->l = insert(i, s, t->l);
    }
    else
    {
        t->r = insert(i, s, t->r );
    }
  
    return t;
}
```

Pay attention to that using the typedef declaration for the pointer type is a bad idea. It only confuses readers of the code.